# Converting the received data into binary form in python

Tags: python

I want to convert the received `hex data` into `binary` form. I get `ValueError`.
For example, I want the first value in the output to be printed as `0000`.

```
    received_data = " ".join("{:02x}".format(byte) for byte in (data))
    print(received_data)
    P_data = "{0:b}".format(received_data[0:1])
```

**Output:**

```
    01 04 04
```

**Error:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\Try\test1\test2.py", line 22, in 
   <module>
    P_data="{0:b}".format(received_data[0:1])
    ValueError: Unknown format code 'b' for object of type 'str'
```

Comment: Why the intermediate hex representation? Going from from a stream of bytes to a stream of binary strings would be more straightforward.

Comment: You're probably looking for `'{0:b}'.format(byte).zfill(8)` ? You said binary form not hex?

Comment: @NPE , hex is used for another purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first convert your string into an integer

```python
P_data = '{0:b}'.format(int(received_data[0:1], 16)).zfill(4)
```

Comment: If I receive hex in alphabets, it shows some error  `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e'
`

Comment: Effectively, you should use base 16 instead (as it is hexadecimal), I edited my answer.